# Create model for MySQL view and join on it

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I'm doing some prototyping and have a simple model like this

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    staff_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    objects = AsOfManager()
```

Now we need to do queries that require a self join, which written in raw SQL are simply something like this:

```
    SELECT X.* FROM no_chain_samplemodel as X
    JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
         FROM no_chain_samplemodel
         GROUP BY user_id) AS Y
    ON (X.user_id = Y.user_id and X.timestamp = Y.timestamp);
```

This query should return for each user_id what is the last row ordering by timestamp. Each of this "chain" (of user_id related rows) could have thousands of rows potentially.

Now I could use raw SQL but then I lose composability, I would like to return another queryset.
And at the same time would be nice to make also writing raw SQL easier, so I thought I could use a database view.

The view could be just something like this

```
CREATE VIEW no_chain_sample_model_with_max_date AS SELECT user_id AS id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
                        FROM no_chain_samplemodel
                        GROUP BY user_id;
```

So the model that refers to the view could be simply like this:

```
class SampleModelWithMaxDate(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'no_chain_sample_model_with_max_date'

    id = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
```

However there are a few problems:

1. even if managed = False './manage.py makemigrations' still creates the migration for this table.
   I even tried to leave the migration there but replacing the model with raw SQL to create the view
   but no luck.
2. I need now to do select_related to join the two tables and query, but how should I do that?

   I tried a foreign key on SampleModel like this:

   by_date = models.ForeignKey(SampleModelWithMaxDate, null=True)

   but this also doesn't work:

   OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'no_chain_sample_model_with_max_date.by_date_id' in 'field list'")

So in general I'm not even sure if it's possible, I can see other people that are using models with views and just for querying the independent model that works also for me, but is it possible to do anything smarter than that?

Thanks

Comment: It is still not clear from your question what you need? Could you provide an example given the django model at the top?

Comment: Well I just need to translate that SQL query using the Django ORM.

So since joining on the same table seems basically impossible without a foreign key pointing to itself, I thought that a view and another model would solve the issue.
But I haven't really seen any example of someone using a db Model based on a db view as I'd like to, so I wonder if that's possible at all.

Comment: That's alright but what is the end result you expect. Do you want to get all the instances of `SampleModel` for each `user_id` with latest `timestamp`?

Comment: Yes that's correct you're right it's not very clearly explained thanks

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any ORM method to get what you want in one query but we could kind of do this with two queries:

First, we get max `timestamp` for all the users

```
latest_timestamps = SampleModel.objects.values('user_id')
                        .annotate(max_ts=Max('timestamp')).values('max_ts')
```

Here `values(user_id)` works as `group by` operation.

Now, we get all the instanecs of `SampleModel` with the exact timestamps

```
qs = SampleModel.objects.filter(timestamp__in=latest_timestamps)
```

---

**PostgreSQL speficic answer:**

You could mix [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) and [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to achieve what you want:

```
SampleModel.objects.order_by('user_id', '-timestamp').distinct('user_id')
```

**Breaking it down:**

```
# order by user_id, and in decreasing order of timestamp
qs = SampleModel.objects.order_by('user_id', '-timestamp')

# get distinct rows using user_id, this will make sure that the first entry for 
# each user is retained and since we further ordered in decreasing order of
# timestamp for each user the first entry will have last row added 
# for the user in the database.
qs = qs.distinct('user_id')
```

Comment: I think I tried that but MySQL does not support "DISTINCT ON" so I didn't really manage to do that..

NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

In [11]: 

In [11]: models.SampleModel.objects.order_by('user_id', '-timestamp').distinct('user_id').count()

Comment: oh yes, `distinct` only works in postgres. Let me see if I can find something for mysql.

Comment: @andrea_crotti I tried to answer your question without using `distinct`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: This answer does assume that no two `timestamp` values would be same for a `user_id`.

Comment: Yes we are actually probably moving to Postgres, which makes everything much nicer, thanks!